# Correlation matrix for big data set in R

Tags: r, correlation

I have the huge data (2e5 x 56). I want to find correlation matrix for rows i.e., correlation between each pair of rows. Then I will get a 2e5 x 2e5 correlation matrix, which is very big. So my system hangs, R crashes.

I am using `rcorr` from `Hmisc` package.

Is there any way I can split and run, so that I cover all the possible pairs?

Comment: What is `2lakh` and should this mean something to us?  Please give us exact dimensions.  For starters, `corr(1,2)` = `corr(2,1)`, in other words you only need to deal with an upper or lower diagonal of your matrix (factor of 2 savings).

Comment: I won't advise you to use a `2e5 x 2e5` correlation matrix without any form of regularization.

Comment: @tim yes that number matters. Because that is where I want correlation.

Comment: @cryo111 then how to find the correlation between each rows? my objective is to find the rows which are highly correlated.

Comment: You are going to need to crank out some code for this.  Just iterate over all combinations, but only store the result if it be within your threshold.  And you should verify that there won't be a massive number of positive hits when you run this code.

Comment: @tim iterating over all combinations is of very high time complexity and my laptops memory crashes.

Comment: corr(a[i,j]) where i and j are values from 1 to number of rows.

So this is best stored in a nested for loop, right

N=NULL

for i in (1:length(dataset)){

    for j in (1:length(dataset)){

        N(i,j)= corr(a[i,j])

}
}

except R is this superfriendly language.

So best option is using lapply ( or related) and maybe trying out foreach